# Swift 3 - button in .xib custom tableviewcell is not performing action

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3, addtarget

I have a `tableviewcontroller`, where i have created custom tableviewcell in a .xib files.

The button (myButton) is used on myCustomTableViewCell.xib has an outlet to myCustomTableViewCell.swift

I have set an action for the button in the TableViewController.swift file

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

let cell = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("myCustomTableViewCell", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! myCustomTableViewCell    

cell.myButton.setTitle(arrayOfMyData[indexPath.row].myText, for:.normal )

//other code to set some other cell.attribute values like above (all works)

cell.myButton.actions(forTarget: "myAction", forControlEvent: .touchUpInside)

}
```

and elsewhere in the TableViewController.swift I have the action:

```
func myAction(sender: UIButton){
    print("pressed myButton")
}
```

but myAction is never called / "pressed myButton" is never printed. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [`addTarget(_:action:for:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrol/1618259-addtarget) method to add the action for your button not the [`actions(forTarget:forControlEvent:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrol/1618251-actions).

The function `actions(forTarget:forControlEvent:)` returns the actions that have been added to a control. It doesn't add a `target/action`.

```
cell.myButton.addTarget(self,action: #selector(myAction(sender:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

Comment: thank you. i actually had it as addTarget previously but didn't have the syntax right and in looking for a fix found the actions... greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: @Dave Welcome mate :)